# How to manage SharePoint hosted app with app-only calls

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, apps-development

I have one SHarePoint Hosted app. I given in `appmanifest.xml` as app only calls and given scope as tenant.

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true" >
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
  </AppPermissionRequests>
```

This app will create folders for each user by taking input from user. Even though the user is having only read only permission on that library, app should create folder behalf of the user.

But if I deploy this app and try for an user who is having edit permission, it is giving `Access Denied` error.

What would be the case in this scenario. Do I need to create any object in javascript file for app-only calls in order to fulfill my requirement? I googled but I did't get any proper information on SharePoint Hosted apps with app-only calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AppOnlyPolicy` is not applicable to SP Hosted app as it uses OAuth tokens. You have to give user permission to make this work.

According to [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179892(v=office.15).aspx#Approve)

> Apps that do not make OAuth authenticated calls (for example, apps that are only JavaScript running in the app web) cannot use the app-only policy. They can request the permission, but they will not be able to take advantage of it because doing so requires passing an app-only OAuth token. Only apps with web applications running outside of SharePoint can create and pass app-only tokens.

Comment: I dont know this principle in sharpeoint hosted app. It is really helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Mihir: Thanks, Please mark it as answer if it solved your query